# Using ES256 algorithm with jwt-dotnet for Apple AppStore

Tags: c#, jwt, app-store

I'm trying to generate a `jwt` token to connect to AppStore API. I'm using the [jwt-dotnet](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt) library to do this.

Apple requires `ES256` to be used and the `jwt-dotnet` is asking for a public key to do the job. I only downloaded a private key from AppStore. How do I handle this?

Here's my code:

```
public static string GenerateAppStoreJwtToken()
{
   var header = new Dictionary<string, object>()
   {
      { "kid", "MY_VALUE" },
      { "typ", "JWT" }
   };

   var scope = new string[1] { "GET /v1/apps?filter[platform]=IOS" };
   var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
      { "iss", "MY_VALUE" },
      { "iat", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() },
      { "exp", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20).ToUnixTimeSeconds() },
      { "aud", "appstoreconnect-v1" },
      { "scope", scope }
   };


   IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new ES256Algorithm(???); // What am I going to use here?
   IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
   IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
   IJwtEncoder encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);

   var token = encoder.Encode(header, payload, privateKey);

   return token;
}
```

Comment: You can generate a public key from a private key. But are you sure you have the private one? Because its usually not given in an API scenario.

Comment: I downloaded a `p8` file from the AppStore and that file includes the private key.

Comment: Yhan you should be able to generate a public one... Check online for tooling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the final solution that worked for me. I ended up switching to `jose-jwt` but I'm pretty sure you can handle the same thing with `jwt-dotnet`. I just found working with `jose-jwt` a bit easier. Here's the link to `jose-jwt`: https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt

And here's the final code. Please note that I did indeed use the private key I find in the `p8` file and didn't have to convert anything. So the `privateKey` parameter I'm passing to the `GenerateAppStoreJwtToken()` function comes directly from the `p8` file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Jose;
    
public static string GenerateAppStoreJwtToken(string privateKey)
{
    var header = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "alg", "ES256" },
        { "kid", "MY_VALUE" },
        { "typ", "JWT" }
    };
    
    var scope = new string[1] { "GET /v1/apps?filter[platform]=IOS" };
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "iss", "MY_VALUE" },
        { "iat", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() },
        { "exp", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15).ToUnixTimeSeconds() },
        { "aud", "appstoreconnect-v1" },
        { "scope", scope }
    };
    
    CngKey key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);

    string token = JWT.Encode(payload, key, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, header);
 
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone, like me, who usew JWT-dotnet elsewhere so doesn't want to use a different JWT package, this worked:

- Converted the apple private key by removing the header and footer ("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" etc) and removing the end of line characters to make a single string for easier storage.
- Convert from Base64 and store in a ReadOnlySpan

  ```
       ReadOnlySpan<byte> keyAsSpan = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
       var prvKey = ECDsa.Create();
       prvKey.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(keyAsSpan,out var read);
  ```
- Create the algorithm. A blank ECDsa instance is needed to prevent an NullException but it is not needed just for signing the token, only verifying which isn't necessary.

  ```
        IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new ES256Algorithm(ECDsa.Create(), prvKey)
  ```

I was able to receive a reply token from apple using this method.

==Edit== Added full method

```
    public string GenerateAppleSecret(string client_id, string TeamId, string kid, string key)
    {
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1);
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> keyAsSpan = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        var prvKey = ECDsa.Create();
        prvKey.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(keyAsSpan,out var read);
        return new JwtBuilder()
            .WithAlgorithm(new ES256Algorithm(ECDsa.Create(), prvKey))
            .AddHeader("kid", kid) 
            .ExpirationTime(now.AddDays(5).UtcDateTime)
            .IssuedAt(now.UtcDateTime)
            .Issuer(TeamId, )
            .Audience("https://appleid.apple.com")
            .Subject(client_id)
            .Encode();
    }
```

The result of this method is appended to the query url as "client_secret" and "client_id" is also included.

Comment: Could you please provide the full method? I'm getting 400 error

Comment: AuthorizationCode leaves only 5 minutes, and can be used only once. Otherwise, I'm getting 400 error. I haven't found this information anywhere except apple official documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

Comment: I've added the full method to the answer above. It regenerates the secret string for each transaction but not sure now if that was required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an aid to anyone else struggling to implement this with .Net without installing something like jose-jwt and jwt-dotnet. Sometimes they simply can't be installed. E.g. using a JWT with an SSIS package under SQL/Server. This code works for .Net 4.5+. I use Dictionary<string,object> but anonymous types works just fine.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace JWTExample
{
    class JWTExample
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Not needed in higher versions of .Net
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            //I've included 2 calls, one returns simple JSON and the other a gz file
            GetUserList();
            GetSubscriberReport();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Press enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void GetUserList()
        {
            string sJWT = GetAccessToken();
            string sUrl = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users";

            HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
            wRequest.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            wRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + sJWT);
            wRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            wRequest.Timeout = 300000;
            wRequest.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse wResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader srRead = new StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swWrite = new StreamWriter("UsersJSON.txt"))
                {
                    swWrite.Write(srRead.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }

        }

        static void GetSubscriberReport()
        {
            string sJWT = GetAccessToken();
            string sUrl = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter[frequency]=DAILY&filter[reportDate]=2023-05-21&filter[reportSubType]=DETAILED&filter[reportType]=SUBSCRIBER&filter[vendorNumber]=81234567&filter[version]=1_3";

            HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
            wRequest.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            wRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + sJWT);
            wRequest.ContentType = "application/a-gzip";
            wRequest.Accept = "application/a-gzip";
            wRequest.Timeout = 300000;
            wRequest.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse wResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse();

            using (Stream drRead = wResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (FileStream swWrite = File.OpenWrite("Subscriber.tab.gz"))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
                    int nBytes = buffer.Length;
                    do
                    {
                        nBytes = drRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (nBytes > 0) swWrite.Write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
                    } while (nBytes > 0);
                }
            }

        }

        static string GetAccessToken()
        {
            //Strip carriage returns and -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- from the key.
            //It's generally considered good practice to store this securely somewhere but for demo purposes this is fine.

            const string API_KEY = "MIGTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqd8nSsc3" +
                                   "RWrZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZh+SdiLn" +
                                   "bLvGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzwMhuSii" +
                                   "JJVaRtC8";

            CngKey cryptoCngKey = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(API_KEY), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);

            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            Dictionary<string, object> dictHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"alg" , "ES256" },
                {"kid" , "MMxxxxx5F7"}, //You get this when the key is created
                {"typ" , "JWT"}
            };

            string sHeaderJSON = jsSerialiser.Serialize(dictHeader);

            //If using .net 4.6 or higher Unix timestamps can be created using DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
            Dictionary<string,object> dictPayload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"iss", "6xxxxe6f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5b8xxxxxx4d1" }, //This is at the top of the API Key create page
                {"iat", DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds },
                {"exp", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds },
                {"aud", "appstoreconnect-v1" }
            };

            string sPayloadJSON = jsSerialiser.Serialize(dictPayload);

            string sJWT = "";

            using (ECDsaCng cryptoECDSA = new ECDsaCng(cryptoCngKey))
            {
                //Base64 encoding is different to Base64URL encocoding. ='s must be trimmed, +'s replaced by -'s and /'s replaced by _'s
                //Alternatively you can add Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens from NugGet and use the Base64UrlEncoder.Encode method
                //See... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.base64urlencoder

                cryptoECDSA.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
                string sUnsignedJWT = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sHeaderJSON)).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_') + "." +
                                      Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sPayloadJSON)).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
                byte[] bSignature = cryptoECDSA.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sUnsignedJWT));
                sJWT = sUnsignedJWT + "." + Convert.ToBase64String(bSignature).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
            }

            return sJWT;

        }

    }

}
```